# SSL certificate error

Tags: curl, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am testing SSL access to a local node server with key,ca,cert in options ( self-signed w OpenSSL)

```
var server_options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/self-signed/server.key'),
  ca: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/self-signed/server.csr'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/self-signed/server.crt')
};
```

trying to access it:

```
curl -v --user 1234567890:abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz --data "grant_type=password&username=yves&password=123456789" https://macMini.local:8000/oauth/token
```

using curl I get the following error:

> curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
>   error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

I downloaded the ca certificate from http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and add them to my curl-ca-bundle-new.crt file, as suggested in some posts related to curl... but no way

here is the log

> - About to connect() to macMini.local port 8000 (#0)
>
>   - Trying 192.168.1.14...
>   - connected
>   - Connected to macMini.local (192.168.1.14) port 8000 (#0)
>   - SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
>   - SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
>   - SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
>   - SSLv3, TLS alert, Server hello (2):
>   - SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
>       error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
>   - Closing connection #0
>       curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
>       error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
>       More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

I know I can bypass the Curl CA checking, using:

```
curl -k -v --user 1234567890:abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz --data "grant_type=password&username=yves&password=123456789" https://macMini.local:8000/oauth/token
```

in which case it's running fine, I can see:

> SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate (18), continuing anyway.

but I'd like to know if there is any way to solve this issue...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's your self-signed certificate that you should add to your CA bundle. Otherwise, curl can't know it can be trusted.

Comment: thanks, I just had some difficulty to find where the cacert.pem was located on OSX (10.8) see above....

Answer (score 5):

I finally found the location on OSX (10.8) :   /usr/share/curl/cacert.pem
so I added my self-signed certificate to it, and the restarted my node-ssl server..

then curl command is now running fine wo the -k option

```
curl -v --user 1234567890:abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz --data "grant_type=password&username=yves&password=123456789" https://macMini.local:8000/oauth/token

* About to connect() to macMini.local port 8000 (#0)
*   Trying 192.168.1.14...
* connected
* Connected to macMini.local (192.168.1.14) port 8000 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /usr/share/curl/cacert.pem
  CApath: none
...
```

Comment: Generally it's better form to include an "update" section in the question rather than provide your findings as an answer

Comment: @MarkFox no, it's not. [If original poster found an answer, it should be an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278050/editing-self-answer-out-of-question)

Comment: @om-nom-nom you're right — in some cases it is better to update, but I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

On mac, I was getting similar ssl relating error while trying to install [composer](https://getcomposer.org).

> error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate

for the command

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
```

But I **successfully** installed it by running the command

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin/composer/
```

as per instructed [here](https://gist.github.com/kkirsche/5710272).