# PHP cURL -> download file with certicifate & password

Tags: php, curl, https, download, ssl-certificate

I have a cert file "cert.p12" and a password for this cert "yxc123yxc".
With this I can authenticate to a website do download a xml file.

how can I do this in php? Tried it like this, but "$response" is FALSE.

```
$cert = "cert.p12";
$pass = "yxc123yxc";
$url  = "https://url.to.download";

$curlhandle = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
#curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_PORT , 443); 
curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, getcwd() . $cert);
curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, $cert);
$response = curl_exec($curlhandle);
```

Comment: Start with using of a function [`curl_error`](http://php.net/curl_error) to see, what's wrong.

Comment: curl_error -> unable to use client certificate (no key found or wrong pass phrase?)

Comment: Great so you have probably wrong path to the certificate, password or certificate. I would check them in that order.

Comment: Try for example `file_exists(getcwd() . $cert)`.

Comment: Also I guess that `getcwd` returns path without an ending slash, so your certificate path is wrong - there is missing slash before the file name. Try `echo  getcwd() . $cert`. How it looks?

Comment: var_dump( file_exists(getcwd() . $cert) ); => TRUE
ckecked the password, it is correct

Comment: openssl_pkcs12_read( $cert, $certs, $pass)
var_dump( $certs );

=> returns NULL

maybe an openssl problem on the server?

Comment: openssl version -> "OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010"

Comment: I would definitely suggest you to upgrade OpenSSL to a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is wrong path to the certificate, since PHP function [`getcwd`](http://php.net/getcwd) return path without an ending slash. Therefore your path to the certificate probably looks like this:

*/var/www/website/directorycert.p12*

Also it's absolutely essential for programming to know how to debug your programs. Always use functions, which return you error codes and messages of operation you are trying to debug. Also print values of variables to see, if they contain what you expect.

You can also use some debugger (for PHP there is for example one called [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org)). If you connect your IDE with that debugger you don't have to print value of variables manually, you can step through your scripts etc.

Comment: path ist correct -> var_dump( file_exists(getcwd() . $cert) ); -> TRUE

Comment: Interesting. According to PHP documentation, there should be no ending slash in return value of the function `getcwd`.

Answer (score 0):

just added

```
curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, "P12");
```

to the php Code

=> curl_error: 
   SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
   error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Comment: OK, I'm pleased you have solved your issue. Please mark it as answer so it can help others.

Comment: So why did you post it as an answer?

Comment: Try to google error message you got (or its parts). For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351052/ssl-certificate-error

Comment: To update this answer a little, now that CURL doesn't support SSLV3 remove the following line: `curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);`