# Composer installing library not working

Tags: php, composer-php, tcpdf

I installed composer on my mac to install a few libraries I need for a project. Specifically tcpdf to generate pdfs. Everytime I run in terminal :
composer require tecnickcom/tcpdf,
I get the following output :

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: Failed to enable crypto
  failed to open stream: operation failed


require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Does anyone know what this error mean? 
thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot establish SSL connection with Composer with PHP 5.6.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28283789/cannot-establish-ssl-connection-with-composer-with-php-5-6-3)

Comment: I looked at that question and it doesnt seem like that is my issue. I have checked for certificates and its all fine.

Comment: Possible open issue: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2798