# How can i install laravel/dusk?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-dusk, phpunit

I am getting this error when trying to install **laravel/dusk** using composer, i tried the following commands.

```
composer require laravel/dusk
composer require --dev laravel/dusk
```

This is the error

```
Content-Length mismatch, received 63447 bytes out of the expected 1616896
http://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
```

My project is using **Laravel 5.5**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Composer Content-Length Mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635257/composer-content-length-mismatch)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28284774/2693543

Comment: Just to note that Packagist has been having intermittent network issues over the last day or so, so it might be a problem on that side

Comment: @iainn - you might right on the money, I have been having an issue when running `composer update` since yesterday.