# Verify that the CA cert is OK (SSL Error on Localhost)

Tags: php, apache, curl, wampserver, mandrill

I'm receiving the following error, which I cannot seem to figure out how to fix on my localhost (WampServer).

PHP is version 5.4.3 and Apache 2.2.22

```
An email sending error occurred: Mandrill_HttpError - API call to 
messages/send-template failed: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA
cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL
routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

I've added the line to both php.ini files and phpForApache.ini, to no avail.

```
[curl]
curl.cainfo = "c:\wamp\cacert.pem"
```

Have also tried various combinations of this, but no luck. Perhaps I need a different cacert.pem? I'm using http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351052/ssl-certificate-error

Answer (score 0):

When did you install your WAMP? If it was a while ago then your certificate expired. They are issued for 1 year period I think. You might consider updating your WAMP (it will come with a new certificate) or generating new certificate on your own. 
In any case, as the error message states there is something with the certificate not that it is not recognized by CA. When it is not recognized by CA you would want update php.ini and perhaps download a new PEM file.